# Host customized (smaller) jQuery UI vs. link to full-size (large) download from CDN?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cdn

Should I link to the full jQuery UI **-or-** provide a slimmed-down customized copy?

There is a very significant size difference between the full jQuery-UI from a CDN like Google vs. providing a customized minimal version. Additionally, one can combine jQuery, jQuery UI, plug-ins, and local code into one single minified JavaScript download.

On the other hand, the chances of a user having a customized copy cached are nil unless they've visited the site previously.

Are there any jQuery CDN "penetration" stats or studies that lend insight into which might be better?

Comment: Another thing to remember is that, If they load the data off the google cdn, the content is served through a localized server, vs, me being in NZ and loading off your US hosted server (example only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually take a look at the components I would be using from jQuery UI and only if I am using 50% or more of the components in it I would use the full UI from the CDN.

Here is some great reasoning and (a bit outdated) stats from http://zoompf.com/blog/2010/01/should-you-use-javascript-library-cdns

The issue obviously is that not all sites do it, and not all use the same CDN which keeps lowering the probability for a hit. On top of that then there's versioning, if you need an older version then that'll keep lowering the probability.

I dfntly use it for jQuery itself since the probability for a hit seems higher and also the other benefits that come with it defeat the overhead of DNS lookups.

Comment: @haknik, **GREAT POINT** in suggesting a split: use a CDN for jQuery, but serve jQuery UI locally. Why didn't I think of that? I am using less than 50% of jQuery UI and I like your reasoning. In particular, versioning was another issue I thought of that lowers "hit" probability. Also, the jQuery UI CSS file can be loaded from the CDN or locally as well (which then affects the source of all the CSS images). Browsers have connection-per-domain limits that make it more effective to use multiple domains at once; thus, I like the idea of using CDN for jQuery and the UI CSS, but not jQuery-ui.js